# Remove Button is deleting all img tags and not the selected one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my image uploader:

[image: My Image Uploader LINK]

**My Code for adding an image which works perfect:**

```
   jQuery(function($){

  // Set all variables to be used in scope
  var frame, selections, attachment,
      metaBox = $('#gallery-meta-box.postbox'), // Your meta box id here
      addImgLink = metaBox.find('.upload-custom-img'),
      delImgLink = metaBox.find('.delete-custom-img'),
      imgContainer = metaBox.find('.custom-img-container'),
      imgIdInput = metaBox.find('.custom-img-id' );
    // Add image from frame
    addImgLink.on( 'click', function( event ){

        event.preventDefault();

        // If the media frame already exists, reopen it
        if ( frame ) {
            frame.open();
            return;
        }

        // Create a new media frame
        frame = wp.media({
            title: 'Select Images',
            button: {
            text: 'Add Image'
            },
            multiple: true  
        });

        // When an image is selected in the media frame
        frame.on( 'select', function() {
            // Get media attachments details from the frame state
            selections = frame.state().get('selection');
            selections.map(function(attachment){
                attachment = attachment.toJSON();

                // Send the attachment URL to our custom image input field
                imgContainer.append(
                  '<li>'    
                + '<img data-attachment-id="id-media-1993'+attachment.id+'" src="'+attachment.url+'" class="gallery-thumbnail" alt="'+attachment.title+'" style="max-width:150px; max-height:150px;"/>'
                + '<a class="delete-custom-img" href="#">Remove Image</a>'
                + '</li>');
                // Send the attachment id to our hidden input
                imgIdInput.val(attachment.id);

                console.log(attachment);
            });
        });

        // Finally, open the modal on click
        frame.open();

    });
```

// MY DELETE BUTTON :

```
    imgContainer.on( 'click', delImgLink, function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var galleryThumbnail = $(this).find('img');

        console.log(galleryThumbnail);
}); 
});
```

When you do watch the image uploader you can see the remove links. When I click on the remove and it doesn't matter which one of the remove button it's giving my the id's of both and same for the src.
see result:

[image: RESULT AFTER CLICK IN CONSOLE]

When I click on the remove link, I want information about the current image, not all the images inside my div element.

Hopefully someone can explain it.

Comment: If I understand correctly, imgContainer contains all images? If so, the console output is exactly what you'd expect. Wouldn't you simply have to bind the click event to the <a> and then use .siblings(img)?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts, not even 'in style'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that, while you are using event delegation to handle dynamic elements, the delegation is pre-determined, so does not pick up the elements correctly

```
delImgLink = metaBox.find('.delete-custom-img'),
```

Change

```
imgContainer.on( 'click', delImgLink, ...
```

to

```
imgContainer.on('click', 'a.delete-custom-img',
```

then `this` will be the button and you can find the relevant image either with `.closest().find()` or `.prevAll("img").first()` (or other method):

```
imgContainer.on('click', 'a.delete-custom-img', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var galleryThumbnail = $(this).closest("li").find('img');
    console.log(galleryThumbnail);
});
```

---

In your original code, if `this` was the delete button then

```
$(this).find('img')
```

would not find anything as find find child items and there are no child items under your delete anchor, so `this` must be referring to something else, higher up.

Answer (score 0):

You need jquery `closet()` to find nearest img and then delete it.
Or you can do it by

```
$(this).parent().find('img');
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected reult, use below option of adding event to imageContainer images and $(this) will provide the details of selected image

```
  $(".imgContainer img").on( 'click',  function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var galleryThumbnail = $(this);

        console.log(galleryThumbnail[0].id);
});
```

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/VQJoZj

Comment: The img tags are added dynamically, so this wouldn't work